# Why <meta> and <title> tags are ordered in this way?

Tags: html, reference, conventions, specifications

```
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
 <title>Test Title</title>
 <meta name="description" content="">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

Why is two **meta** tags always go before **title** and others afterwards?

Is there any reason (compatibility, coding references or rules) I can't place all the meta tags before title?

Comment: I've only heard of placing `<script>` tags after `<link>` tags. I don't think this has any real meaning.

Comment: I have never thought it mattered.

Comment: See http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-meta-element.html#charset

Comment: To expand on @bfrohs, the HTML5 specification states that the charset `<meta>` element must appear in the first 1024 bytes of a document. So the sooner, the better, as it eliminates the possibility that a long `<title>` element might push the charset meta beyond the first kilobyte of the file.

Answer (score 5):

The browser needs to know the character encoding as soon as possible. Other elements (including the title) can contain characters which only have meaning (or the correct meaning) in the specific encoding being used.

There is no need for any other meta elements to appear before the title.

> Is there any reason (compatibility, coding references or rules) I can't place all the meta tags before title?

The sooner the title appears, the sooner the browser can display it (in the title bar, tab, etc).

Answer (score 2):

It's partly un-necessary, but from a strictly theoretical view, it makes sense.

If you consider you first tell the browser it's a `<HTML>`, document it's dealing with, then that the content/characterset is `UTF-8`, so then the browser will know how to properly treat the `title` text, with the correct character set.